# Paint Brush Offset

Tags: texturing, image

When I use the image editor's paint brush the color is applied at the wrong location.  Instead of painting at the cursor it paints a couple pixels up and to the right. Makes doing fine detail work frustrating.  The old version I had worked correctly,  when I updated today the problem started.  In the 3d view the brush is correctly lined up.

Any one know how to fix this?